# previous section name

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, numbering

Is there a way to get the title [short] and the number of the *previous* and the *next* sections?

For the current section somehow I have access to:

```
\sectiontitle % where is it defined I wonder
\thesection
```

So, I can calculate, for example, the counter of the previous section:

```
\the\numexpr\thesection-1\relax
```

What I'm missing is something like

```
\prevsectiontitle, \nextsectiontitle ?
```

Comment: This deliberately depends on the document class and requires hacking into the `section` commands

Comment: You should **not** rely on the output of `\thesection` giving the pure number. Rather use `\the\numexpr\value{section}-1\relax` for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A version with saving automatic generated labels containing the information on section titles to the `.aux` file and extracting the previous, the current and the next section title.

The counter `sectioncntr` is never reset automatically, it continues to count the number of sections in the document and at each `\refstepcounter` of this counter a `\zlabel` is set, which stores the `sectiontitle` property which has been defined before with `\zref@newprop`.

The short names `\Xtitle`  where `X` stands for `previous`, `current` or `next` do not insert links to the section header, whereas the long names `\Xsectiontitle` insert links. See the example with the page footer for an application.

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage[user,hyperref]{zref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[L]{\previoussectiontitle}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\currenttitle}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\nextsectiontitle}
}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter

\zref@newprop{sectiontitle}[unknown]{\@currentsectiontitle}
\zref@addprop{main}{sectiontitle}

\newcounter{sectioncntr}

\newcommand{\previoustitle}{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{sectiontitle:\the\numexpr\c@section-1}{}{%
    \zref@extract{sectiontitle:\the\numexpr\c@section-1}{sectiontitle}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\currenttitle}{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{sectiontitle:\number\value{section}}{}{%
    \zref@extract{sectiontitle:\number\value{section}}{sectiontitle}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\nexttitle}{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{sectiontitle:\the\numexpr\c@section+1}{}{%
    \zref@extract{sectiontitle:\the\numexpr\c@section+1}{sectiontitle}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\previoussectiontitle}{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{sectiontitle:\the\numexpr\c@section-1}{}{%
    \hyperlink{\zref@extract{sectiontitle:\the\numexpr\c@section-1}{anchor}}{\zref@extract{sectiontitle:\the\numexpr\c@section-1}{sectiontitle}}
  }%
}

\newcommand{\currentsectiontitle}{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{sectiontitle:\number\value{section}}{}{%
    \hyperlink{\zref@extract{sectiontitle:\number\value{section}}{anchor}}{\zref@extract{sectiontitle:\number\value{section}}{sectiontitle}}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\nextsectiontitle}{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{sectiontitle:\the\numexpr\c@section+1}{}{%
    \hyperlink{\zref@extract{sectiontitle:\the\numexpr\c@section+1}{anchor}}{\zref@extract{sectiontitle:\the\numexpr\c@section+1}{sectiontitle}}
  }%
}




\xpatchcmd{\@sect}{%
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
}{%
  \def\@currentsectiontitle{#7}
  \ifnum0=\pdfstrcmp{#1}{section}
  \refstepcounter{sectioncntr}\zlabel{sectiontitle:\the\c@section}%
  \fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
}{%
  \typeout{Patch Success}
}{%
  \typeout{Patch Failure}
}
\makeatother


\usepackage{hyperref}



\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
\subsection{Foo subsection}
\blindtext[20]
\section{Foobar}
\blindtext[20]
\section{Next Foo}
\blindtext[20]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I assumed an `article` - like class here. `book` will be a little bit more complicated in order to prevent sections from previous or next chapters to be shown as well

Comment: It is designed for `\section`, not for `\section*` however

Comment: Thank you, Christian. I'm  using a `book`-like class (with a single chapter per document though). Your `\xpatchcmd{\@sect}` **fails**. Also, eventually I'm redefining \section for auto-labeling as follows

    `\LetLtxMacro{\oldsection}{\section}
    \RenewDocumentCommand \section{sm}
    {\IfBooleanTF{#1}
 {\oldsection*{#2}\label{sec:#2}}
 {\oldsection{#2}\label{sec:#2}}
    }`

Comment: I'm using [extbook](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/extsizes/extbook.cls)

Comment: @user612313: Yes, that's why it is important to provide a complete example and not only `wishes`. Patching must fail with `xparse` macros! You should update your question with the minimal working document

Comment: I was looking for a general approach and your fantastic solution showed a clever way. I'm currently adapting it to my situation and will post my customizations. But then again, people are going to have different setups, and your solution will always serve as a good starting point. Thanks again, Christian, great job!

Comment: One more question, how do I check for the "empty" `\nexttitle` when we come to the end of document? `\ifdefempty` and `\ifcsempty` don't recognize it as empty: is it a whitespace?